# Windows 10 with early build npm fails to install any modules due to 'bad signature'

Tags: node.js, windows, openssl, npm-install

I'm am installing 64-bit Node v7.10.1 (which uses npm v4.2.0) on my brand new Windows laptop (Windows 10 Pro, Version 20H2, Build 19042.1645).  My application needs this early version of Node unfortunately.
So far I have installed Node using three different processes: nvm for Windows, NVS and direct download.
I've scanned the Net looking for solutions and found many similar issues but very few possible solutions.  My question is a duplicate of [npm install fails with bad signature error on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62178866/npm-install-fails-with-bad-signature-error-on-windows), but the suggestions there don't help me.  I feel the need to re-raise this issue.

After installing Node and creating a new directory to work in, I issue the command
`npm install path`
The response I get is this:

```
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "path"
npm ERR! node v7.10.1
npm ERR! npm  v4.2.0
npm ERR! code EPROTO
npm ERR! errno EPROTO
npm ERR! syscall write

npm ERR! write EPROTO 101057795:error:1408D07B:SSL routines:ssl3_get_key_exchange:bad signature:openssl\ssl\s3_clnt.c:2032:
npm ERR!
npm ERR!
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this error at:
npm ERR!     <https://github.com/npm/npm/issues>

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\pdqsw\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2022-04-13T13_45_23_254Z-debug.log
```

I've tried using a different registry and used http instead of https for it.
I've tried setting strict-ssl to *false*.

If I install Node 8.0.0, which uses npm v5.0.0, then path installs perfectly.

What is very frustrating is that I did a similar setup two or three years ago on another W10 laptop and that has been working with Node 7.10.1 (installing many modules) for all that time.
Thanks in anticipation of receiving some clues to resolving this.

Edited 19/04/2022:

In trying to find a way around the above problem I have installed WSL for Windows 10 with Ubuntu Linux.  This allowed me to install Node 7.10.1 no problem, and with npm now installing modules happily.  My system is now running (or seems to be) perfectly and I can still easily edit my program files using VSC in the Windows environment.  So I think I shall stay with this configuration, at least for now.

Comment: can u pls describe in detail for your solution. me too facing same issue

Comment: Hi @Remo,
The instructions for installing WSL for Windows are easy to locate on the Microsoft site.  Here are a couple to get you started:
https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/install-ubuntu-on-wsl2-on-windows-10#1-overview
https://www.windowscentral.com/how-install-wsl2-windows-10

After installing Linux I installed Node using nvm (an excellent Node Version Manager). 
 Then I put a link from my Linux /app directory there through to my system on the Windows directory.  Then I started up my server using Webpack on the Linux side.  Everything just worked fine.
I hope some of that helps.

Answer (score 5):

I ran into this exact same issue while setting up 64-bit Node v7.x.y (tried multiple versions) on a new Windows 11 machine, surrounded by a similar kind of frustration that 64-bit Node v7.x.y continues to work fine on my somewhat older Windows 10 machine without any such issues.

Surprisingly enough (and perhaps as a workaround), I found out that using 32-bit Node v7.x.y works without running into this issue.

Using NVM for Windows, you could use the following command to install 32-bit Node v7.10.1 on 64-bit Windows.

```
nvm install 7.10.1 32
```

And then use the following command to use 32-bit Node v7.10.1 on 64-bit Windows.

```
nvm use 7.10.1 32
```

So, I have ended up with this option of using 32-bit Node v7.x.y, and so far it's been running smoothly for me without any issues.

Comment: Hi M. Shoaib Surya.  My solution of using Ubuntu Linux worked well and to this day it is still what I use.  Your suggestion sounds good.  Sorry about the late reply, it would have been good to try out your solution.  It seems to have worked for @bharal

Comment: oh it absolutely did the trick on the windows 11 i'm using, was ready to pull all my hair out before this gem appeared.