How to solve this communication problem with npm server via SSL?
I'm redoing an Ionic project with Ionic version 7.0.0 but I can't install Cordova to proceed. I don't have much knowledge about this, but I managed to make it work on the school computer. However, when I try to install it on other computers, it always shows the same error.
npm ERR! Windows_NT 10.0.22631zeTree: sill install loadCurrentTree
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "-g" "cordova@6.3.0"
npm ERR! node v7.0.0
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.8
npm ERR! code EPROTO
npm ERR! errno EPROTO
npm ERR! syscall write

npm ERR! write EPROTO 101057795:error:1408D07B:SSL routines:ssl3_get_key_exchange:bad signature:openssl\ssl\s3_clnt.c:2010:
npm ERR!
npm ERR!
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this error at:
npm ERR!     <https://github.com/npm/npm/issues>

I tried to install the latest version of npm, but any code I write always gives the same error.

what version of nodejs are you using?

@NajamUsSaqib node v7.0.0 & npm v3.10.8. It literately written in the error message. Update you node.js & npm to the latest LTS version dude. They are outdated and no longer maintained.

I know it's an old version, as I'm using a project already made to make my project work, but I managed to make it work on the school computer but I don't know how and I need to make it work on my own PC. I just can't figure out what the problem is. If you could tell me something, it would be of great help. Thank you!

Had the same issue and error log, NPM would work on Win10 but not on Win11, solved it by using 32 bit Node.
Came to this solution through: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73888658/24474887
